Create Bones over multiple Faces
I have a plane I need to create a custom rig for. I need bones at each individual face under 1 armature. Is there a a way to quickly do this?

Select your bone in Edit mode, press ShiftDGX2Enter then ShiftR to repeat. Once you've finished a row on X, select it all and do the same on Y.
